# how to get the running executable jar name using c/c++ code?

Tags: java, c++, ubuntu, swig

I want to get the name of the `running executable jar file using the C/C++` code.

**What did I do?**

Generate dynamic library for the c++ code which contain the the code to get the current executable name.

Created a wrapper file and generated a `.so`(Dynamic library for Linux) to interface with java, using the `swig`.

The created `so` is loaded in the java file which return the  name of the executable.

**What happened:**

It returns the name of the java runtime executable file,`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

**What really I need:**

I need the name of the running executable jar file, in which the code is written in C/C++.

Comment: `java` is the name of the java runtime executable - not the compiler.

Comment: But i need the running executable jar file name

Comment: I understand that,but can u help me to get the name of the executable jar with the c/c++ code, ie)the application name